# Is there a way to loop "backwards" or bottom-up through heavily nested json?

Tags: json, ruby

Is there an efficient way to walk “backwards” or bottom-up through a json file with a LOT of nests? I need to remove all empty fields from a heavily nested json string but since my current logic looks top-down, it only removes the bottommost layer of empty fields.

My data looks something like this:

```
{
    "rule": {
        "description": "authentication_failed",
        "category": {
            "action": "denied"
        }
    },
    "tls": {
        "client": {
            "certificate": {
                "subject": "-"
            }
        },
        "server": {
            "certificate": {
                "subject": "-"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My current code is below, where "event" is the json object:

```
        def removeEmptyFields(event,h,name)
            h.each do |k,v|
                if (v.is_a?(Hash) || v.is_a?(Array)) && v.to_s != '{}'
                    removeEmptyFields(event,v,String.new(name.to_s) << '[' << k.to_s << ']')
                else
                    if v == '' || v == '-' || v == 'none' || v.to_s == '{}'
                        event.remove(String.new(name.to_s) << '[' << k.to_s << ']')
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        removeEmptyFields event,event.to_hash,''
```

My current data output (below) is not ideal. My best outcome would be if the "tls" field was removed all together. Given the way my code currently walks through the json, I haven't been able to get a loop variable to work.

```
{
    "rule": {
        "description": "authentication_failed",
        "category": {
            "action": "denied"
        }
    },
    "tls": {
        "client": {
            "certificate": {}
        },
        "server": {
            "certificate": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to get the output you were aiming for, I only tried it with your example, so feel free to tell me if I was wrong with something. Hope it helps!

```
def removeEmptyFields(json_hash)
  hash = {}
  json_hash.each do |key, value|
    if (!value.empty? && value != '-' && value != 'none') 
    # Filter empty strings, arrays, and hashes

      hash[key] = value.class == Hash ? removeEmptyFields(value) : value
      hash.delete(key) if hash[key].empty?
    end
  end
  hash
end
```